# Center Logo Inside Dynamic li Navigation

Tags: php, html, foreach, nav

So i have a CMS which uses a foreach loop to generate the navigation which consists of individual list items inside a ul.

Basically what I want is to have my logo inserted in the center of these links, with an equal number of links on either side.

I've got my code to split up into two different columns of navigation with a gap, but I cant figure out where to place the logo div so it doesn't repeat more than once, current code also throws out some empty list items which I don't need.

```
<ul>
    <?php $i = 0; foreach($items as $item): ?>
    <li><a<?php ecco($item->isOpen(), ' class="active"') ?> href="<?php echo $item->url() ?>"><?php echo html($item->title());?></a></li>
    <?php if (++$i % 3 === 0 && $i !== count($items)) echo "</li><li>"; endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have written `ecco` instead of `echo`.. Is this just a copy - paste error?

Comment: @Sebsemillia ecco is just a snippet built into the CMS

Comment: I updated my answer, if this doesn't work either I'm clueless..

Comment: You want to discuss a client-side problem here, so please provide client-side _code_ as well (and not some server-side CMS code, where no one here can know what the actual output will be). And please provide an example via http://jsfiddle.net/ or similar as well.

Comment: This is all the related code I have, how can I produce a JSFiddle with PHP involved :) all this does is pulls through file names and converts them to hyperlinks. It doesn't really matter what the content is I just want to split my for-each results up into two separate columns with a centred logo.

Comment: Your server-side script _outputs_ HTML code – and you should be able to view that in your browser and do some simple copy&paste …

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

**UPDATE**

Since your count doesn't work, try this:

```
<ul>
<?php
    $j = 0;
    $breakPoint = 0;
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $j++;
        $breakPoint = $j;
    }

$i = 0;

foreach($items as $item) {      ?>
    if ($i === $breakPoint) {
        /* insert Logo Code */
    } else { ?>
        <li><a<?php ecco($item->isOpen(), ' class="active"') ?> href="<?php echo $item->url() ?>"><?php echo html($item->title());?></a></li>
    <?php   
    }    
    $i++;
} ?>
</ul>
```

Haven't tested it. And it depends if you have a odd or even number of `$item` elements.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, i get no logo showing up at all

Comment: what do you get when you echo `$breakPoint`?

Comment: mhmm, strange. And when you just echo `count($items)`?

Comment: Same again, even though ive got more than one link

Comment: Unsure where to put this updated code, although might be being a bit stupid

Comment: just anywhere where you have access to `$items`, this to test if you can count your $items amount somehow..

Comment: I can confirm its counting correctly using that new code.

Comment: still no logo. Very frustrating

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. But this is as far as I can help you from here.